# Empty value on js object shows up as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

I made a model object, "project", that gets its data from nodejs using mongoose. I display all projects read-only in a grid (table) with *ngFor in a parent component, this is the child component:

```
<td>{{project.name}}</td>
<td>{{project.startDate}}</td>
<td>{{project.endDate}}</td>
<td>{{project.customerName}}</td>
<td>{{project.projectType}}</td>
```

projectType property was not part of the original model, I added projectType to the Schema of project while there were already some documents in the collection. If I output those projects like the code above the projectType field in the table displays [object Object].

So this projectType property doesn't exist on these js-objects but it should just display an empty string in that case.

How come it is showing [object Object], is that standard null object display? And how to fix?

**EDIT**: I was assuming the projectType field was empty but I accidentally filled it up with an other object. Just checking console log of the object revealed this.

Thank you

Comment: Have you console.log of projects ? Do you have an *ngIf to prevent load undefined?

Comment: Because apparently the type of that field is an object and when you use ToString on an object, you get `[object Object]`. Try to output the value to the console, to make sure what the value of this property is.

Comment: Provide code where you set the projectType. Also provide the model object.

Comment: `console.log('%O', project.projectType)`

Comment: I was assuming the projectType field was empty but I accidentally filled it up with an other object. Just checking console log of the object revealed this, just a minor mistake. Thanks @Jerodev